# jqGrid and POST verb

Tags: post, jqgrid, get

I've used jqGrid for long time now, without any kind of problem.
Today I've tried to implement it in ASP.NET MVC 2 project and things didn't work as expected.
After a little struggle I've realized that now controllers do not accept GET calls when returning JSON data. It is for security reasons.
If I force my controller to support GET - forcing the JSON response like this:

```
return(Json(value, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet))
```

... and specifying

```
[AcceptVerbs( HttpVerbs.Get )]
```

on the method

everything works fine and my jqGrid shows the results.
I've tried to change the verb of the jqGrid **myType: 'POST'**
but the grid stops working. 
I've done a little bit of debugging and tracing and it seems that jqGrid never POSTs the request.
My controller always receives a GET.

Is there anybody who can help me, please.

Thanks

Alberto

SAMPLE:

```
jQuery("#ProvincesDynamicGrid").jqGrid({
    url: '<%=Url.Action("Fetch", "Provinces")%>',
    postData: { id: '0' },
    datatype: 'json',
    myType: 'POST',
    colNames: ['Descr', 'Prov', 'Regione'],
    colModel: [{ name: 'Description', index: 'Description', editable: false, resizable: true, sortable: false, width: 200, align: 'right' },
               { name: 'Initial', index: 'Initial', editable: true, editrules: { required: true, custom: true, custom_func: ValidateInitialColum }, resizable: true, sortable: false, width: 90, align: 'right' },
               { name: 'RegionDescription', index: 'RegionDescription', editable: false, resizable: true, sortable: false, width: 200, align: 'right' }
              ],
    pager: $('#ProvincesDynamicPager'),
    rowNum: 11,
    // rowList: [10, 20, 50],
    width: 748,
    height: 253,
    viewrecords: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    scroll: false,
    rownumbers: true,
    hidegrid: false,
    caption: 'Gestione Province',
    cellEdit: true,
    cellsubmit: 'remote',
    cellurl: '<%=Url.Action("SaveProvince", "Provinces")%>',
    onSelectRow: function(id) {
        SelectedRowId = id;
    },
    beforeSaveCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {

    },
    afterSubmitCell: function(serverresponse, rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
        var resp = jQuery.parseJSON(serverresponse.responseText);
        // if (resp.Status == false)
        return ([resp.Status, resp.Message])
        //alert(resp.Message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tony suggested in the jqGrid forum I was mispelling the **mtype** parameter (myType: 'POST')
So the exact code would be like this:

```
jQuery("#ProvincesDynamicGrid").jqGrid({
    url: '<%=Url.Action("Fetch", "Provinces")%>',
    postData: { id: '0' },
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['Descr', 'Prov', 'Regione'],
    colModel: [{ name: 'Description', index: 'Description', editable: false, resizable: true, sortable: false, width: 200, align: 'right' },
               { name: 'Initial', index: 'Initial', editable: true, editrules: { required: true, custom: true, custom_func: ValidateInitialColum }, resizable: true, sortable: false, width: 90, align: 'right' },
               { name: 'RegionDescription', index: 'RegionDescription', editable: false, resizable: true, sortable: false, width: 200, align: 'right' }
              ],
    pager: $('#ProvincesDynamicPager'),
    rowNum: 11,
...
```

Now everything works fine.